# How can a custom icon be loaded in an add-on?

Tags: scripting, add-on

I have created an add-on but I can't apply my own icon to the operators in this add-on.

Is there any easy way to implement this?

Or do I need to add the icon to an SVG file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [script custom previews in a menu](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47504/script-custom-previews-in-a-menu)

Answer (score 6):

You can only use already available icons, too see which are available enable the Icons add-on. A panel with all icons will be displayed in the text editor properties (or python console). The name of the icons is shown in a tooltip.

You can use the icon attribute like:

```
row = layout.column(align=True)
row.operator('id_name', icon='QUESTION')
```

[image]

Custom icons require compilation which is off-topic here but you could find a discussion on custom icons at [this BA thread](http://www.blenderartist.org/forum/showthread.php?290960-Possible-to-create-a-custom-icon-for-UI-panels-buttons).

Possibly outdated information on how to integrate custom icons you find in the [Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/How_to/Add_an_icon). There is descibed that all icons are stored in a single .png file which explains that you can't use SVG or any other format.

Answer (score 2):

If your addon draws using opengl (via the `bgl` module) you can draw your own images directly, however this is *not* accessible while drawing typical buttons & layouts.

You can however do this from: (http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_release/bpy.types.Space.html?highlight=draw_handler_add#bpy.types.Space.draw_handler_add) unfortunatly using these callbacks is currently undocumented but you can see examples in scripts distributed with blender.

Comment: Very useful link but I'm still searching the Examples for That 'Space type' script

Comment: Math Vis addon is one, though it draws mostly in 3d space (except for text).