# Blender python custom mouse cursor

Tags: python, scripting, interface, 3d-view

Is there a way I can change or modify my mouse cursor in the 3d view while my custom operator is running?

Comment: I've noticed that blender seems to use it's own crosshair cursor in edit mode (it doesn't look anything like the crosshair cursor in my cursor theme).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search for [cursor](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/search.html?q=cursor&check_keywords=yes&area=default) yields [Window.cursor_set](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Window.html?highlight=cursor#bpy.types.Window.cursor_set)

So i.e.

```
bpy.context.window.cursor_set("HAND")
```

Comment: Thank you but is there a way I can create my own shape?

Comment: It is not possible [yet to use custom icons](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/how-can-a-custom-icon-be-loaded-in-an-add-on). I guess it is also not possible to use your own shapes except using bgl and set the cursor to "NONE".