# script custom previews in a menu

Tags: python, interface, add-on

I want to know how to create a menu with previews for an add-on. Until now I know that this is related with the `bpy.utils.preview`. I'm making an add-on that appends objects from a .blend file, I know how to append objects but what I want to do is to create a menu with previews of the objects /(similar to the matcaps menu - see below), select them and then press an "import button" to append the object.

Here's some documentation about the module:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.previews.html
https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/templates_py/ui_previews_dynamic_enum.py

[image: matcap menu]

Also, as this is an add-on I don't know if I should have a `def register()` and a `def unregister()` inside this .py file as well as in the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Add some more details and I will be glad to help. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "menu with previews that executes a class when a preview is pressed". Maybe add pictures or expand your description so others can understand.

Comment: Yes sure. Sorry this is my first question on this site :/

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look and see if I can help. Do you already have images for the previews, or do you need the script to render for you..

Comment: I already have them, I just want a way to load each image with an specific id that I can write and track for future functions

Comment: Sorry that it took so long! I got it working! (finally) :)

Comment: you mentioned possibly using a script to render previews of objects.  That is something I would love to see.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By analyzing the two provided scripts, as well as the free version of Pro Lighting: Skies I was able to understand how to create a previews menu.

[Here is my script](https://gist.github.com/natecraddock/7bf6b74768b377f260b7) that I commented in if you want to study it.
If you run it in Blender's text editor, it will create a panel at the bottom of the Object properties area.

The key parts of what you want to do are:

## Create a property collection

This happens in the `register` function so only one is created. Because you want the the images folder to be predefined, we hard-code the location inside of the script. You also set a globally defined `preview_collections` variable to hold the collection. Then you create an `EnumProperty` to hold the images. This has a function to generate the images from the folder.

```
pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
pcoll.images_location = bpy.path.abspath('//images')
preview_collections["thumbnail_previews"] = pcoll
bpy.types.Scene.my_thumbnails = EnumProperty(
    items=generate_previews(),
    )
```

## Generate Previews

In the `generate_previews` function, we create a pcoll object that references the one we created in the `register` function.

```
def generate_previews():
    pcoll = preview_collections["thumbnail_previews"]
    image_location = pcoll.images_location
    VALID_EXTENSIONS = ('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')

    enum_items = []

    # Generate the thumbnails
    for i, image in enumerate(os.listdir(image_location)):
        if image.endswith(VALID_EXTENSIONS):
            filepath = os.path.join(image_location, image)
            thumb = pcoll.load(filepath, filepath, 'IMAGE')
            enum_items.append((image, image, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    return enum_items
```

## Access the values

We can then access this preview collection in any Blender UI Panel with

```
row=layout.row()
row.template_icon_view(context.scene, "my_thumbnails")
```

Or however else you named it. Then you can use `bpy.context.Scene.my_thumbnails` to access the currently selected image name. From there you can create an append button to append from a file based on the image name.

---

## Using in an Addon

To use this method in an addon, you need to change a line in the Previews.py file. Instead of getting the location of the images folder based on the current .blend file, you need to get it based on the location of the addon. So change

```
pcoll.images_location = bpy.path.abspath('//images')
```

to

```
pcoll.images_location = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "images")
```

In the `__init__.py` file, the `register` and `unregister` functions need to call the `Previews.py`'s register and unregister functions.

```
def register(): 
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    Previews.register()


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    Previews.unregister()
```

And finally, because you use `bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)` you need to remove the register_class call in the `Previews.py` file to register the UI class, or it will be called twice.

```
# Delete this, as well as the one in the unregister function from Previews.py
bpy.utils.register_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)
```

I have updated the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/natecraddock/7bf6b74768b377f260b7) on GitHub with the changes.

Comment: Is your addon in a folder?

Comment: Yes. it's in a folder inside the script folder, I think it is related with the '__init__.py' file

I leave you here the links with the source code

http://www.pasteall.org/65655/python
http://www.pasteall.org/65653/python

Comment: Sorry for delete and write comments over and over, the site doesn't allow me to edit them

Comment: I will take a look!

Comment: @AlejandroTorres I got it to work! Check out the edited answer.

Comment: @Zachman It works, thank you, you're awesome, Do you have an email or any way to contact you to tell you when my addon will be ready and send you a free copy?

And another question related with the script, Is there a way to change the thumbnails folder according to a category in a checklist?

Comment: @AlejandroTorres Yeah! Just click on my name and there is a link to my website. On my website you can scroll to the bottom and find my email! I can answer your other question from there

Comment: @AlejandroTorres Hmm... that worked better on mobile. Try [here](http://natezcraddock.com/).